# pointer string not returning expected output

Tags: c, pointers, reverse, c-strings, function-definition

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    
    void revstr(char str[])
    {
        char temp;
        int size = 0;
        while(*str != '\0'){
            size++;
            str++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < size/2; i++)        
        {
            temp = str[i];               
            str[i] = str[size-1-i];
            str[size-1-i] = temp;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            printf("%c\n", *(str+i));
        }
    }
    int main()
    {
        char str[20];
        printf("enter a string: \n");
        scanf("%s", &str);
        revstr(str);
        return 0;
    }
```

why is my rev string not printing the reverse of the string it is printing out some garbage value.
can you point out why?

Comment: `***void revstr(char str[])` is not cut-n-pasteable code.   It is much more useful if you provide code samples that are easy to work with.

Answer (score 2):

After this while loop

```
    while(*str != '\0'){
        size++;
        str++;
    }
```

the pointer str does not point to the beginning of the string.

Instead you could write for example

```
    while( str[size] != '\0'){
        size++;
    }
```

Nevertheless such a function should do only one thing: to reverse a string. It is the caller of the function that decides whether to output the reversed string.

So the function can look like

```
char * revstr( char s[] )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    while ( s[n] ) ++n;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n / 2; i++ )
    {
        char c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[n - i - 1];
        s[n - i - 1] = c;
    }

    return s; 
}
```

and in main you could write

```
puts( revstr( str ) );
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * revstr( char s[] )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    while ( s[n] ) ++n;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n / 2; i++ )
    {
        char c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[n - i - 1];
        s[n - i - 1] = c;
    }

    return s; 
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "Hello";
    
    puts( s );
    puts( revstr( s ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello
olleH
```

Of course instead of the while loop you could use the standard string function `strlen`.

```
size_t n = strlen( s );
```

Pay attention to that in the call of `scanf`

```
scanf("%s", &str);
```

the second argument shall be the expression `str`

```
scanf("%s", str);
```

Comment: in scanf("%s", &str) is also working fine there is no problem in that. the problem was in the while loop where I changed the address of str. Thanks for the ans

Comment: @nabeelkhan If something works as expected it does not ,mean that it is correct.

Comment: @nabeelkhan In my function there was a typo in the word while. I updated the code.

Comment: @nabeelkhan `scanf("%s", &str)` is absolutely not working.  What happens when you do `echo 'this is a relatively long string' | ./a.out`?  (hint, the behavior is undefined).   You want `if( scanf("%19s", str) == 1 ){  ... }`

Comment: Whether you use `&str` or `str` is, I suppose, a matter of taste, but `str` is definitely preferred.  Eventually, the code will be modified and `str` will become allocated on the heap, and suddenly all the usages of `&str` will be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement it another way:

```
char *reverse(char *str)
{
    char *wrk = str, *end = str;

    if(str && *str)
    {
        while(*(end + 1)) end++;
        while(end > wrk)
        {
            char tmp = *end;
            *end-- = *wrk;
            *wrk++ = tmp;
        }   
    }
    return str;
}
```

1. It is good to check if the parameter is correct.
2. I would return the value. It allows you to use the reversed string in expressions and as a function parameter. Example below:

```
int main(void)
{
    char s[] = "Hello world";

    printf("%s\n", reverse(s));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/fbo4nsn38

Answer (score 0):

In your code you advance the pointer *str* to calculate its length but you forgot to reset it to the start after that. Also, your call to scanf should pass *str*, not its address. Moreover scanf will write beyond the end of *str* if the user enters a string longer than 19 characters. Try this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void revstr(char str[])
{
    char temp;
    int size = strlen(str);
    for (int i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {
        temp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[size - 1 - i];
        str[size - 1 - i] = temp;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char str[20];
    printf("enter a string: \n");
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
    str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';
    revstr(str);
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```